# If $G$ acts on $X$ proper discontinuously then It acts proper discontinuously on deformation retarct of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $G$ acts proper discontinuously on a topological space $X$,

Suppose $X$ deformation retracts onto $A$,

Under what condition we can conclude that $G$ acts proper discontinuously on $A$.

Comment: My view: This is always true. A more stronger version, If $G$ acts p.d.c on $X$ then it acts p.d.c on every subspace.

Comment: Yes, just follow the definition.